# Shortcut keys on mac

Tags: shortcut

Transitioning from working on windows to Mac.  I can't figure out how how to make shortcut keys work for menu items.  Specifically, turning on Walk mode on the Navigation menu.

Thanks

Comment: [Shift F] to enter Fly Mode. Use WADS keys to control direction. Then [Tab] to turn on gravity so you will fall and collide with objects below you and walk on them. I use this on Macs, but as far as I know the shortcuts are not Mac-specific.

Comment: You can change the key bindings in the User Preferences Editor->Input